# How to set newff (neural network toolbox function) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I got error after I run my simple code. Thanks

Here is my code

```
input_training_data = HandWritingData(random_list,:)'; %size = [256X788]
target_training_data = Category(random_list,:)'; %size = [10x788]
net = newff(minmax(input_training_data), [15 10], {'logsig','logsig'} , 'hardlim' ); 



Error in ==> Neural_Network_code at 19 
net = newff(minmax(input_training_data), [15 10],
{'logsig','logsig'} , 'hardlim' ); %create a network
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a number of reasons why you wouldn't want to work with newff , but RTFM:

newff Create a feed-forward backpropagation network.

Obsoleted in R2010b NNET 7.0.  Last used in R2010a NNET 6.0.4.
   The recommended function is feedforwardnet.

Syntax

```
 net = newff(P,T,S)
 net = newff(P,T,S,TF,BTF,BLF,PF,IPF,OPF,DDF)
```

Description

```
 newff(P,T,S) takes,
   P  - RxQ1 matrix of Q1 representative R-element input vectors.
   T  - SNxQ2 matrix of Q2 representative SN-element target vectors.
   Si  - Sizes of N-1 hidden layers, S1 to S(N-1), default = [].
         (Output layer size SN is determined from T.)
 and returns an N layer feed-forward backprop network.

 newff(P,T,S,TF,BTF,BLF,PF,IPF,OPF,DDF) takes optional inputs,
   TFi - Transfer function of ith layer. Default is 'tansig' for
         hidden layers, and 'purelin' for output layer.
   BTF - Backprop network training function, default = 'trainlm'.
   BLF - Backprop weight/bias learning function, default = 'learngdm'.
   PF  - Performance function, default = 'mse'.
   IPF - Row cell array of input processing functions.
         Default is {'fixunknowns','remconstantrows','mapminmax'}.
   OPF - Row cell array of output processing functions.
         Default is {'remconstantrows','mapminmax'}.
   DDF - Data division function, default = 'dividerand';
 and returns an N layer feed-forward backprop network.
```

hardlim is not a transfer function. Use trainlm of trainbg.

```
net = newff(minmax(input_training_data), [15 10], {'logsig','logsig'} , 'trainlm' );
```

Comment: What do you suggest if I should not use newff?

Comment: feedforwardnet() is recommended from matlab documentation . You can also use network() , for more specialised things like cascade networks you should use check the documentation.